# i am getting an out of bounds error for a lambda/stride slice

Tags: python, tensorflow

i am trying to create a mask-rcnn model based of of this repos https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN

when creating the model i get an error

`slice index 0 of dimension 1 out of bounds. for 'lambda_4/strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [?,0], [2], [2], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0 0>, input[2] = <0 1>, input[3] = <1 1>.`

i have looked it up but have not found any solution that has worked.

i have tried installing different library versions for tensorflow but that has only caused more errors.
i have also tried switching to a gpu and tpu runtime and this has not helped, one thing that i am not sure may help or not is when on a gpu runtime the `lambda_4/strided_slice` changes to `lambda_16/strided_slice`.

i believe the error has to do with tensorflow but i am not entirely certain.

i am new to all of this so help would very much be apprecieated :) thankee!

EDIT: this is the code i used

```
!pip3 install -r /content/Mask_RCNN/requirements.txt
!python3 /content/Mask_RCNN/setup.py install


#getting keras versions right so it works properly


!pip uninstall keras -y
!pip uninstall keras-nightly -y
!pip uninstall keras-Preprocessing -y
!pip uninstall keras-vis -y
!pip uninstall tensorflow -y
!pip uninstall h5py -y




!pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
!pip install keras==2.0.8
!pip install h5py==2.10.0


import os
import sys
import random
import math
import re
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Root directory of the project
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("/content/Mask_RCNN")

# Import Mask RCNN
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)  # To find local version of the library

from mrcnn.config import Config
from mrcnn import utils
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn import visualize
from mrcnn.model import log

%matplotlib inline 

# Directory to save logs and trained model
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs")

# Local path to trained weights file
COCO_MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
# Download COCO trained weights from Releases if needed
if not os.path.exists(COCO_MODEL_PATH):
    utils.download_trained_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH)



class pathsConfig(Config):
  NAME ="Paths"

  GPU_COUNT=1
  IMAGES_PER_GPU=2

  NUM_CLASSES =1+1 #BACKGROUND +PATH

  # If enabled, resizes instance masks to a smaller size to reduce
  # memory load. Recommended when using high-resolution images.
  USE_MINI_MASK =True
  MINI_MASK_SHAPE=(56,56)

  IMAGE_MIN_DIM= 100
  IMAGE_MAX_DIM=1024
  IMAGE_PADDING =True

  IMAGE_META_SIZE=0
  # Image mean (RGB)
  MEAN_PIXEL = np.array([123.7, 116.8, 103.9])

  #Number of ROI's per image to feed to mask/ classifier heads
  TRAIN_ROIS_PER_IMAGE=128

  # Percent of positive ROIs used to train classifier/mask heads
  ROI_POSITIVE_RATIO = 0.33

  # Pooled ROIs
  POOL_SIZE = 7
  MASK_POOL_SIZE = 14
  MASK_SHAPE = [28, 28]

  # Maximum number of ground truth instances to use in one image
  MAX_GT_INSTANCES = 100

  # Bounding box refinement standard deviation for RPN and final detections.
  RPN_BBOX_STD_DEV = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2])
  BBOX_STD_DEV = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2])

  # Max number of final detections
  DETECTION_MAX_INSTANCES = 100

  # Minimum probability value to accept a detected instance
  # ROIs below this threshold are skipped
  DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE = 0.7

  # Non-maximum suppression threshold for detection
  DETECTION_NMS_THRESHOLD = 0.3

  # Learning rate and momentum
  # The paper uses lr=0.02, but we found that to cause weights to explode often
  LEARNING_RATE = 0.002
  LEARNING_MOMENTUM = 0.9

  # Weight decay regularization
  WEIGHT_DECAY = 0.0001
      
  def __init__(self):
    """Set values of computed attributes."""
    # Effective batch size
    self.BATCH_SIZE = self.IMAGES_PER_GPU * self.GPU_COUNT

    # Input image size
    self.IMAGE_SHAPE = np.array([self.IMAGE_MAX_DIM, self.IMAGE_MAX_DIM, 3])

    # Compute backbone size from input image size
    self.BACKBONE_SHAPES = np.array(
        [[int(math.ceil(self.IMAGE_SHAPE[0] / stride)),
          int(math.ceil(self.IMAGE_SHAPE[1] / stride))]
          for stride in self.BACKBONE_STRIDES])

  def print(self):
    """Display Configuration values."""
    print("\nConfigurations:")
    for a in dir(self):
        if not a.startswith("__") and not callable(getattr(self, a)):
            print("{:30} {}".format(a, getattr(self, a)))
    print("\n")





config=pathsConfig()
config.display()


#created model using the confing above and will save it to the model directory specified above 
pathmodel = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="training" , config=config , model_dir=MODEL_DIR)


#load weights to use for model

init_with ="coco"

if init_with =="imagenet":
  model.load_weights(model.get_imagenet_weights(),by_name = True)
elif init_with=="coco":
  # Load weights trained on MS COCO, but skip layers that
  # are different due to the different number of classes
  # See README for instructions to download the COCO weights

  model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH,by_name=True,exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits","mrcnn_bbox_fc","mrcnn_bbox","mrcnn_mask"])

elif init_with=="last":
  model.load_weights(model.find_last(),by_name=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

ok so i have solved the problem , it was out of bounds since the IMAGE_META_SIZE was 0 and it was trying to convert that to a tensor hope this helps anyone that comes across it in future !